# What are the little "X"'s next to the notes?

Tags: piano, notation, accidentals

This is an excerpt from Etude in C# minor.

What do the little X's next to the notes mean?

[image]

Do I have to play these any special way? Is it an accent mark?

Comment: Please don't delete duplicates. They help others find this question and the other answers on the site.

Comment: Answer: It is a double sharp. F goes ## to G.